# How to continue a loop until reaching a pre-established confidence interval?

Tags: matlab, while-loop, confidence-interval

I have a `for`-loop of this type:

```
n = 10;
all_values = cell (n,1);
for i = 1:n
   do something (series of operations)
   all_values{i} = [result1; result2]
end
```

Now, I would like to convert it into a `while`- loop (therefore independent of `n`) that ends when a confidence interval between two consecutive results of the iterations is reached, in the specific when:

```
result1 {n,1}(1,1) - result1 {n-1,1}(1,1) <= 0.1
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `all_values{i)`??? Please fix this

Comment: Is `result1{n,1}(1,1)` set in each loop iteration i.e. as part of `do something (series of operations)`? Also how do you intend to handle the first iteration where `result1 {n-1,1}(1,1)` does not exist?

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your reply. I fixed the mistyped parenthesis. Yes, result {n,1}(1,1) changes at every iteration as result of a series of operation. Regarding the first iteration you're right; then I would propose to start to check the confidence interval only after the second iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most literal translation of your loop is:

```
n = 3;
%// assumes first two values are already set
while ~(result1 {n-1,1}(1,1) - result1 {n-2,1}(1,1) <= 0.1)
    %// do something (series of operations in which result1 {n,1} is set)
    all_values{n} = [result1; result2];
    n = n + 1;
end
```

or

```
n = 2;
%// assumes first value is already set
while n == 2 || ~(result1 {n-1,1}(1,1) - result1 {n-2,1}(1,1) <= 0.1)
    %// do something (series of operations in which result1 {n,1} is set)
    all_values{n} = [result1; result2];
    n = n + 1;
end
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of while loop I am looking for. Is there a similar way to implement it that does not need to have the first value already set?
Maybe I could run the for loop for n = 2 and then continue as you suggested.

Comment: @GiovanniRinaldi that is the same thing as setting the first two values. You can set them any way you like, using a `for`-loop is a totally acceptable way. I would suggest that you abstract out as much of the content of the loop into a function as you can so you don't write the same code in both your loops. Otherwise use the second option and change the `n == 2` condition to `n <= 2` and then you actually don't have to preset anything. That's probably the simplest way to go. Note this only works if you use the short-circuiting `||` operator as opposed to the bitwise `|` operator.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using cells but with regular arrays it is simple. Here I'm randomly computing

```
all_values = zeros(2,1);
result1 = 100;
while result1 - all_values(end-1,1) > 0.1
   result1 = rand;
   result2 = rand;
   all_values = [all_values [result1; result2]];
end
```

Then you get your values stored in every column. But even this is not good practice since your array is growing uncontrollably.

I would recommend defining a maximum iteration count and initialize everything as such. You can delete later the unnecessary columns if not needed.